# #NAME when linking Excel workbooks with IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to link multiple workbooks to one workbook in the same folder. This needs to be done every month with a new set of workbooks linking to the master workbook.

The workbooks that need to be updated/changed also change their naming convention in respect to the date and therefor I used IF.

My end goal is to copy the master in each folder, one for every month, and also have the workbooks that I need linked to it in the folder.

My first attempt, for February, worked but when I created the new March folder I get #NAME in the cells that are suppose to be linking.

My formula:

```
=IF($A$2="20190101",'S:\Office\Billing & Collecting\Northstar\Account Reconciliations\Generation\Jan 2019\[MD 19502_KWHIN_20190101_20190201.xlsx]MD 19502_KWHIN_20190101_2019020'!B3,IF($A$2="20190201",'S:\Office\Billing & Collecting\Northstar\Account Reconciliations\Generation\Feb 2019\[MD 19502_KWHIN_20190201_20190301.xlsx]MD 19502_KWHIN_20190201_2019030'!B3,IF($A$2=”20190301”,'S:\Office\Billing & Collecting\Northstar\Account Reconciliations\Generation\Mar 2019\[MD 19502_KWHIN_20190301_20190401.xlsx]MD 19502_KWHIN_20190301_2019040'!B3 ...continued for each month
```

The paths all seem to be correct and I get this when I show the calculation steps;

[image: Calculation steps]

When I press evaluate it shows **`IF("20190301"=#Name?.'S:\…`**

Comment: `”20190301”` within your formula has two left quotes. Try deleting it and replacing it with`"20190301"`

Comment: Incidentally, this approach with a nested `IF` for every month will quickly get out of hand. It might make sense to set up a lookup table, which will also be much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The `#NAME?` error indicates there is unrecognized text within your formula.

The section of your formula referring to March has right quotes instead of straight quotes: ...`IF($A$2=”20190301”,`... should be ...`IF($A$2="20190301",`...